# How to position camera vertically in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a model that is starting at the center of the screen but I want to display it starting at the bottom. I have tried to change the perspectiveCamera, max and min distance and scene scale but I'm unable to figure it out so far. Here is the code

```
        // renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

        // scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 40);

        scene.add(camera);

        // controls
        var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.addEventListener('change', render);
        controls.minDistance = 10;
        controls.maxDistance = 95;
        controls.enablePan = true;

        // ambient
        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .2));

        // light
        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
        camera.add(light);

        new GLTFLoader().load('models/female.glb', function (gltf) {

            gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {

                if (child.isMesh) {
                    child.material.normalMapType = THREE.ObjectSpaceNormalMap;
                    child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

                    child.visible = true
                }

            });
            gltf.scene.scale.set(4, 4, 4)
            scene.add(gltf.scene);

            render();
        });
```

And the model looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your camera higher up by putting some suitable number for y in your:

camera.position.set(0, 0, 40)

Also the orbit controls may have a way to set the target object.